# Remove keyboard indicator in Gnomebuntu 13.10

Tags: gnome, keyboard, indicator

I'm running the new Gnomebuntu in a VM and would like to disable the keyboard indicator from my task bar as it looks pretty ugly. Does anyone know how I go about doing this? There are plenty of posts on here for this in Unity but I'm unaware as to the whether the same process applies.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a real solution, but if you remove all but one layout, the indicator disappears.

Answer (score 0):

[System Settings] -> [Text Entry]
Then un-check the box 'Show current input source in the menu bar' at the bottom left of the options page.